# NullPointerException - FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I unexpectedly received a null pointer exception error while loading my fragment activity. I was referring to FrameLayout to direct user to another activity (upon button click).

```
11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at com.dooba.beta.ThirdFragment.onCreateView(ThirdFragment.java:22)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-10 07:31:58.773: E/AndroidRuntime(10340):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the activity code:

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_city, container, false);

        FrameLayout icity = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.flCityBac);
        icity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        return rootView;


    }


}
```

below is the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_gridview_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >

        <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/background"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ttitle"

          android:padding="5dp"
         android:alpha="0.9"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >



       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flCityBac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="30" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_cityBac"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="175dp"
          android:alpha="1"
          android:background="@drawable/vancouvero2"
          android:contentDescription="@null"
          android:paddingLeft="0dp"
          android:paddingRight="4dp"
           />

      <TextView
              android:id="@+id/text_Title"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="40dp"

              android:layout_gravity="bottom"

              android:padding="0dp"

              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:gravity="center"
                                           android:background="#E41B17"
              android:alpha="0.85"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:text="Vancouver, Canada"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:typeface="serif" />



              </FrameLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Discover"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#E41B17"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which line is 22? there something is null

Comment: What is the name of the layout file?

Comment: thanks for your response. below is line 22         FrameLayout icity = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.flCityBac);

Comment: name of layout of file is activity_city. The MainActivity it is refering to extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: Instead of getView().findViewById try to use rootView.findViewById

Comment: thank you the above suggestion solved my problem. May i ask the difference between getView and rootView

Comment: @user3907211 I wrote an answer. Please, accept it as the correct answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3907211 Only after onCreateView method is called you can access your fragment's view using getView(). Before that, your fragment has no view. The rootView is the inflated view that will be linked to your fragment after onCreateView is finished. Please, take a look: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.flCityBac);
```

Use:

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.flCityBac);
```

You cannot use getView because your view was not created yet.

Hope it helps you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_city, container, false);

        FrameLayout icity = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.flCityBac);//Use rootView here.
        icity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        return rootView;


    }


}
```